# Terrible flushing - Duravit Starck 2 Happy D

Tags: plumbing, toilet

My two Duravit Starck 2/Happy D toilets have turned me into a full-time toilet scrubber. Any suggestions before I replace them?

The problems:

- Fecalpheliac bowls. "Matter" seems to stick tenaciously on the bowl.
  I must scrub the bowl after each and every usage.
- Poor flushing. I must flush two and sometimes three times to clear
  the bowl. So much for "lo flush" water conservation.
- Long refill times. One toilet takes 90 seconds.

What I've done:

- Cleaned the fill lines and filters.
- Adjusted and re-adjusted the fill levels in the tank.
- Had a plumber examine the bowls. He said "It's a shame - they're so expensive."
- Asked my Duravit supplier. Their answer: "Most Europeans use a scrub
  brush."
- Written scathing "Happy D" reviews - "SAVE YOURSELVES! It's too late
  for me!"

In short: Pretty to look at. Awful to use.

Comment: I have seen TV commercials for a product that is sprayed into or poured into the toilet bowl before use which is advertised to prevent feces from adhering to the toilet inside surfaces. As I have aged I seem to foul the toilet surface significantly more than when I was younger. (But this is far from the worst difficulties of being in the 8th decade of human life.) I keep a large squeeze bottle of water near the toilet and squirt a jet of water on adhering matter to dislodge it. Maybe $5 for the bottle. Not perfect but is an improvement. Keep searching for a solution short of replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know anything about your toilet, but I have 2 types in my house. I have 2 Kohler Cimarron 2 model K4421 which are great and a new American Standard  Champion 4 max just recently installed. The American Standard is supposed to be able to flush a bucket of golf balls. Don't tell my p..p that. It doesn't always go down completely. I would choose the Kohler. Also we use " never scrub " cartridges to help keep the bowl clean.

Comment: I've noted your recommendation of the Kohler.  I'll try NeverScrub.  Thanks! -Scott